# How do I select a data-state to use in a jquery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select certain buttons that have a data-state="start", so that when the user clicks on the buttons, the function randomly selects from an array. I just don't know how to select my data-states... Here is some of the code:

```
$("").on("click", function() {
    var randomPick = Math.floor(Math.random() * comPicks.length);
    alert(randomPick);
  });
```

I'm trying to select the buttons with the data-state="weapon"...

`<button class="btn btn-info btn-block" data-state="weapon">ROCK</button>`

Comment: Are you trying to get the value of `data-state`? Or are you trying to select elements that have the `data-state` attribute?

Comment: I'm trying to select the buttons with the data-state="weapon"...
<button class="btn btn-info btn-block" data-state="weapon">ROCK</button>

Comment: Ok, then see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to select elements that have the `data-state` attribute set to a certain value, you can use this plugin:

```
$.fn.filterByData = function(prop, val) {
    return this.filter(function() {
        return $(this).data(prop) == val;
    });
};
```

Now, you can use `$('button').filterByData('state', 'start')` to get a list of all `button`s that have a `data-state="start"` attribute.

If all you want is to get the actual value of the `data-state` attribute in the function, you can just use `$(this).data('state')`

Answer (score 0):

One way is just have the `data-type` in the query

```js
$("input[data-type='start']").on("click", function() {
    var randomPick = 10;//changed to show example
    alert(randomPick);
});
$("button[data-type='start']").on("click", function() {
    var randomPick = 20;//changed to show example
    alert(randomPick);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' data-type='start' value='Click me'/>
<button data-type='start'>Button</button>
<input type='button' value='Does nothing'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click", "[data-state=start]", function() {
  // do stuff
  var randomPick = Math.floor(Math.random() * comPicks.length);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use selector by attribute :

```
$('body').on("click", "button[data-state='start']", function() {
     //Your code here
})
```

Hope this helps.